# Normalizing line endings in excel cells

Tags: excel, ms-office, newline, line-endings

I have a rather big excel file, which sadly has some inconsistent line endings, meaning that a cell contains a paragraph, and some lines in this paragraph have Unix style line endings(CR), and some have windows style line endings(CRLF). 
It is important to normalize the line endings in the cells, because after exporting to xps format, some xps reader libraries(c#) will not treat the CR character correctly, and just throw exceptions left and right.

I can normalize the line endings manually for 1 cell, but I would like to do it for all the cells in a single operation, as the file contains 30.000+ lines.

Do you know of a way to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Found the question to be inquisitive. Did a little searching on this topic and found [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/03/remove-carriage-returns-excel/) link. 
Sounds to be like solving the problem on hand.

Tried it out and works charmingly.
[image]